# How can is initialize all variables in a Java class at once to zero

Tags: java, variables, constructor, init

I have some Java code with class variables and rather than set them to a particular value, I'd just like to initialize everything to zero. In C/C++, I can just do a memset() on the size of the structure, but how do I do the same thing in Java?

Comment: Consider it done.  (All class/instance variables are inited to zero/null/whatever by default.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitives will default to zero.  Objects will default to null.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.  However, as that article mentions, relying on the default value in Java is considered bad practice.  The better practice is to set them all either when you declare them or in the constructor.

Comment: Why is relying on the tightly-specified behavior of the JVM "bad practice"?

Comment: Java does this for class level variables, but not for local variables (which give you a compile time error if you do not instantiate them before you use them).  So, it makes your code less readable if you don't instantiate them, but start using them.  That's my guess as to why it is a bad practice.

Comment: You shouldn't, as a rule, unnecessarily initialize locals since that initialization occurs every time you execute the code.  Additionally, blindly initializing them to zero/null prevents the compiler from warning you that the variable is *really* uninitialized because you forgot (perhaps only along one path) to set the variable's intended value.

Answer (score 0):

All primitive data types default to zero, only objects (and therefore Strings as well) default to null.
As long as you do not specify a value, all int, long, float, double etc. are 0 / 0.0 and all object and string variables are null.

Answer (score 0):

Java initializes everything to 0 and null. But you should do this in constructor yourself.

Comment: Java does not instantiate local variables at all.

Comment: @JoshEdwards - Java certainly does "instantiate" local variables, in the sense that, when you invoke a method an instance of local variables is created.  What it doesn't do is *initialize* local variables.